# .mktime and .strftime help returning wrong day of week

Tags: php, datetime, strftime, mktime

*Before I get yelled at I am not a php coder and I have searched vary heavily to try and figure this out without luck here and on the net. I have seen some things, but just don't have enough understanding to apply with my limited understanding. The php code was developed by someone who has vanished, so not supporting and I have one little bug I need to try and clean up and why a html/css guy is even trying to figure this out without much luck. So appreciate groups help and patience as well as specificity if possible.*

**Problem:** the php code is returning the wrong day of the week on a statistics report the software generates. So when you go run the statistics page and it queries the DB it returns a value but the wrong day label shows up.

In my test case I have data only on Thursday of the month and when I run the report it shows up as data for Sunday.

Here are what I assume are the two section of code from my research.. rather than posting the entire php file. I guess at least I think I narrowed down the code section...small victories.

The code used to get the first day of the month is (which i have seen out there and compared and looks like it is correct):

```
    function get_first_day($day_number=1, $month=false, $year=false)
{
  $month  = ($month === false) ? strftime("%m"): $month;
  $year   = ($year === false) ? strftime("%Y"): $year;

  $first_day = 1 + ((7+$day_number - strftime("%w", mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year)))%7);

  return mktime(0,0,0,$month, $first_day, $year);
}
```

Before I go on I have also tried to set $day_number=1 to various values 0-6, but seems to have no effect. I read several post that setting that value was the problem, but made no difference for me. I thought maybe the "session" was causing the issue after trying to learn about them, so I tried to log out and log back in clear my cache and also change browsers after changing the value but that got me nowhere.

The code I guess you would say that calls this??? to generate the output report that is not correct is:

```
<table id="graph_weekday" class="data" style="display:none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <caption><?php echo _occupancy_per_week." / "._days;?></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="no_input">&nbsp;</td>
                <?php
                foreach ($label_wk as $value) {
                    echo "<th>".strftime("%A", get_first_day($value, $_SESSION['statistic_month'], $_SESSION['selectedDate_year']))."</th>";
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo _days;?></th>
                <?php
                foreach ($data_wk as $value) {
                    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
                    }
                    ?>
```

So things seem to be working to pull the data, but the label is wrong. Though setting the value for $day_number= to something else doesn't seem to work.

Is there something wrong with the.$value. which is being echoed and I need to apply the get_first_day to the value?

update:
Trying to dig into this, but still need help I found this within the code that I think is also relivent (maybe)

```
// Bar Plot Guest by weekday/month
$data_wk = array();
$label_wk = array();

    $statistic = querySQL('statistic_weekday');

    foreach ($statistic as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $paxsum){
            $label_wk[] = $key;
            $data_wk[] = $paxsum;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like `get_first_day` is supposed to return the first _weekday_ of a given month? Then you getting Sunday from it might be a simple matter of the timezone – because what’s Monday in certain timezones is of course Sunday in some other. So go check your server’s/PHP’s timezone settings.

Comment: I wish it would have been something that simple. The timezone setting is correct for the server global php.ini still now luck [link]stackoverflow.com/questions/3682636/… which uses similar code and I checked my code compared to it so assuming it is something in the second part, but not sure. – @CBroe

Comment: What data are you feeding to the function as first parameter (`$value` in your loop)?

Comment: @CBroe I am not sure since I have never worked with php. The actual stats page is very long. Before posting I tried to research a great deal to include code that I thought was relevant but maybe I missed something that needs to be included to get help?  In my research I traced as much as I could and thought these three peices and of course the SQl query in another file was everything. Should I post he query code?

Comment: The query is more or less just a SELECT SUM of reservation counts as "paxsum" from a table where it meets some criteria and based on the the $_SESSION.  Everything else date related in the tool and in the stats work fine. It is just when it lists the day of week under the data. Its like it starts on the wrong day because the pattern is right just labeled wrong. Meaning that if I have data for three days it graphs it the interval between days is correct but the label is wrong. I ran another test for Monday Thursday Friday and the data came back Sun/Mon/Thur

Comment: Ok I think I have it.  I was changing the value $day_number=1 to a different number.  I wasn't changing the $first_day = 1. When I changed $first_day = 5 it seems to work. Does this seem like it is correct or going to cause me other issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I have it. I was changing the value $day_number=1 to a different number. I wasn't changing the $first_day = 1. When I changed $first_day = 5 it seems to work. Does this seem like it is correct or going to cause me other issues?

```
  function get_first_day($day_number=1, $month=false, $year=false)
  {
    $month  = ($month === false) ? strftime("%m"): $month;
    $year   = ($year === false) ? strftime("%Y"): $year;

    $first_day = 5 + ((7+$day_number - strftime("%w", mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year)))%7);

    return mktime(0,0,0,$month, $first_day, $year);
  }
```